# Weak limit of a bilinear operator

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

I have a bounded bilinear operator $B:X\times Y \to Z$, where $X,Y$ and $Z$ are Banach spaces. That is linear in both variables and satisfies:
$$\|B(x,y)\|_Z \le \|B\|\ \|x\|_X\ \|y\|_Y, \quad \forall (x,y) \in X\times Y.$$

For some sequences $(x_n) \subset X$ such that $x_n \rightharpoonup \bar x$ in $X$, and $(y_n) \subset Y$ such that $y_n \rightharpoonup \bar y$ in $Y$.

My objective is to establish that $B(x_n,y_n) \rightharpoonup B(\bar x,\bar y)$ in $Z$.
I would greatly appreciate any references or suggestions to help me prove this.

I tried with
\begin{align*}
B(x_n,y_n)-B(\bar x,\bar y)= B(x_n,y_n-\bar y)-B(x_n-\bar x,\bar y).
\end{align*}
The second term of the r.h.s converges weakly to zero in $Z$, as the operator $B(.,\bar y): X \to Z$ is linear and bounded. But, I can not see why $B(x_n,y_n-\bar y)$ converges weakly to zero in $Z$.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: The claim is false, a counterexample is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353076/weak-continuity-of-bilinear-forms-on-hilbert-spaces).

Comment: Adding on to the very first comment, if the OP's claim was true, multiplication in any Banach algebra would be weakly continuous, which is absurd.

Comment: *footnote:* I'd just like to note that the multiplication in a Banach algebra can be *jointly weakly sequentially continuous* while it can fail to be jointly weakly continuous. I believe $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with convolution serves as an example. Of course the multiplication may not be *jwsc* at all, as in $K(\ell^2)$, the algebra of all compact operators on $\ell^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false generally as indicated in the comments. However, we can show it holds under additional hypotheses on $X$ and/or $Y$.

A Banach space $B$ is said to have the Dunford-Pettis property (DPP for short) if $x_n\to 0$ weakly in $B$ and $f_n\to 0$ weakly in $B^*$, then $f_n(x_n)\to 0$. We claim that if either $X$ or $Y$ (or both) has DPP, then $B(x_n,y_n)\to 0$ whenever $B$ is bounded bilinear, $x_n\to 0$ weakly in $X$, $y_n\to 0$ weakly in $Y$.

First, some notation: Let $f\in Z^*$, $B:X\times Y\to Z$ be a bounded bilinear operator.

- For each $x\in X$, we can define $\gamma_x\in Y^*$ by $\gamma_x(y) = f(B(x,y))$,
- For each $y\in Y$, we can define $\xi_y\in X^*$ by $\xi_y(x) = f(B(x,y))$.

It is up to the reader to show that if $x_n\to 0$ weakly in $X$ (resp. $y_n\to 0$ weakly in $Y$), then $\gamma_{x_n}\to 0$ weakly in $Y^*$ (resp. $\xi_{y_n}\to 0$ weakly in $X^*$). *Hint: a linear operator is norm-norm continuous iff it is weak-weak continuous. Apply this to the map $X\to Y^*$ (resp. $Y\to X^*$) defined by $x\to \gamma_x$ (resp. $y\to\xi_y$)*

Now, suppose $X$ has DPP. Let $f\in Z^*$ be arbitrary. Let $x_n\to 0$ weakly in $X$ and $y_n\to 0$ in $Y$. Then,
$$f(B(x_n,y_n)) = \xi_{y_n}(x_n)\to 0$$
since $\xi_{y_n}\to 0$ weakly in $X^*$.

If $Y$ has DPP, the result follows verbatim similar as above.

Examples of Banach spaces with DPP are $L^1(X,\mu)$, $L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$ for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(X,\mu)$, and $C(K)$ for compact Hausdorff topological spaces $K$. Reflexive Banach spaces have DPP if and only if they're finite dimensional.

---

As a final note, if $x_n\to x$ weakly, $y_n\to y$ weakly, and $B(x_n-x,y_n-y)\to 0$ weakly in $Z$, then

\begin{eqnarray}
f(\hspace{2mm} B(x_n,y_n) - B(x,y)\hspace{2mm})
&=& f(\hspace{2mm} B(x_n-x,y) + B(x,y_n-y) + B(x_n-x,y_n-y) \hspace{2mm}) \\
&=& \xi_y(x_n-x) + \gamma_x(y_n-y) + f(B(x_n-x,y_n-y))\to 0
\end{eqnarray}
for each $f\in Z^*$; that is $B(x_n,y_n)\to B(x,y)$ weakly in $Z$.

Comment: Thank you, I want to ask if the space $C(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ possesses the Dunford-Pettis property?

Comment: @elmas If a Banach space has DPP, so do every complemented subspace. $C(0,T;L^2)$ is isomorphic to the injective tensor product $C[0,T]\check{\otimes} L^2$ (e.g., Ryan's book on tensor products). $1\otimes L^2 \simeq L^2$ is a complemented subspace of $C[0,T]\check{\otimes} L^2$. Since $L^2$ is reflexive and infinite dimensional, it doesn't have DPP. Thus, $C(0,T;L^2)$ doesn't have DPP.

Comment: Other question please. How about the space $\{ x \in L^{\infty}((0,T)\times (0,1)) : | x(t,s) | \le M\} $. Does it have DPP ?

Comment: @elmas Perhaps you meant $|x(t,s)|\leq M$ almost everywhere. $X:=(0,T)\times(0,1)$, with 2-dim Lebesgue measure on it, is a $\sigma$-finite measure space, so yes for $L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$. By definition, DPP is defined for Banach spaces, not for balls or subsets of Banach spaces.

Comment: Yes that what I meant. I appreciate your clarifications.

Comment: @elmas You're welcome. I'm glad if any of these are useful for your studies/research.